# I can't get MSBuild to ignore an entire folder

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I just started using MSBuild and for whatever reason this seems more complicated than it should be. I'm trying to get the build process to completely ignore "node_modules" folder. I've tried all sorts of ways. Here's my latest:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <DefaultExclude Include="node_modules\*.*" />
  <!-- tried **\node_modules\** -->
  <!-- tried **node_modules** -->
  <!-- tried node_modules\** -->
  <!-- tried several others combinations -->
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>     
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.ascx" Exclude="packages\**;@(DefaultExclude)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.asmx" Exclude="packages\**;@(DefaultExclude)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.css" Exclude="packages\**;@(DefaultExclude)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.html" Exclude="packages\**;@(DefaultExclude)" />      
</ItemGroup>

<Copy SourceFiles="@(InstallInclude)" DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\ResourcesZip\%(RecursiveDir)" />
<!-- this resources directory ends up with all the node_modules in it -->
```

Needless to say, the build process takes forever, and sometimes breaks (inconsistently).

MSBuild is an initial confusing nightmare.

Comment: <DefaultExclude Include="node_modules\*.*" /> and <DefaultExclude Include="**\node_modules\**" /> should be work, it depends on the structure level of the node_modules folder and .csproj. I have test it with your code and it works for me. Have you clear the file in the destination folder before you test with latest configuration? VS will not clear it automatically when you rebuild the project. If you have already clear it, could please share me the structural level in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: Hard to tell the exact problem since you don't show your directory structure... Exclude needs exact path matches, see e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171455.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. Otherwise use a condition like `Condition='%(RelativeDir)' != 'node_modules'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're expanding items based on your node_modules folder. MSbuild will collect metadata for all items which is what makes it slow. To make sure this process is efficient, use a property instead - similar to [what the .net core web sdk does](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/e50ec659a80f19b54837023c2493b73a48911373/src/ProjectSystem/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.Targets/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.props):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefaultItemExcludes>packages\**</DefaultItemExcludes>    
  <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);**\node_modules\**;node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);**\jspm_packages\**;jspm_packages\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);**\bower_components\**;bower_components\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>     
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.ascx" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.asmx" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.css" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.html" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes)" />      
</ItemGroup>
```

An  exclude pattern ending in `\**` will prevent msbuild even enumerating the folder. MSBuild 15 (part of VS 2017) may be required to get the full performance benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the hidden attribute in the offending folder, for example `node_modules` and ASPNET_compiler will skip it. I've tested it with grunt and typescript, and it works fine with the hidden folder.